# How to compose easily two ORs and CI95%

Tags: confidence-interval, odds-ratio

I need to compose ORs and CIs. I have an OR/CI95% for treatment A vs treatment B and an OR/CI95% for treatment B vs treatment C, and I want to get the OR of treatment A vs treatment C with the CI95.
It seems I can multiply ORs and CIs, but I should get a CI99.7%. How can I get the CI95 in cargo cult mode ?
Thanks !

Comment: Cargo cult mode can be dangerous.  Are the treatments randomized?  What are the thought-to-be-important baseline variables to adjust for to account for outcome heterogeneity within treatment groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to perform a network meta-analysis and you do not have the estimated standard errors, only confidence limits.  Typically a confidence interval for an odds ratio is constructed by inverting a Wald test with a log link function, i.e.

$$\text{exp}\Bigg[\text{log}\{\hat{\theta}_{AB}\}\pm1.96\cdot\hat{\text{se}}_{AB}\Bigg],$$
where $\hat{\theta}_{AB}$ is the estimated odds ratio and $\hat{\text{se}}_{AB}$ is the estimated standard error of $\text{log}\{\hat{\theta}_{AB}\}$.  If you are given the  point estimate and confidence limits you can solve for the standard error, i.e.

$$\hat{\theta}^U_{AB}=\text{exp}[\text{log}\{\hat{\theta}_{AB}\}+1.96\cdot\hat{\text{se}}_{AB}]\implies \hat{\text{se}}_{AB}=[\text{log}\{\hat{\theta}^U_{AB}\}-\text{log}\{\hat{\theta}_{AB}\}]/1.96 $$

Let $\hat{\theta}_{BC}$ be the estimated odds ratio between groups $B$ and $C$.  Then the estimated odds ratio between $A$ and $C$ is $\hat{\theta}_{AB}\cdot\hat{\theta}_{BC}$, a product of odds ratios.  The corresponding 95% confidence interval from inverting a Wald test with a log link function is

$$\text{exp}\Bigg[\text{log}\{\hat{\theta}_{AB}\cdot\hat{\theta}_{BC}\}\pm1.96\cdot\hat{\text{se}}\Bigg],$$
where $\hat{\text{se}}=\sqrt{\hat{\text{se}}^{2}_{AB} + \hat{\text{se}}^{2}_{BC} }$ is the estimated standard error of $\text{log}\{\hat{\theta}_{AB}\cdot\hat{\theta}_{BC}\}$ based on the delta method and $\hat{\text{se}}^{2}_{BC}$ is the esitmated standard error of $\text{log}\{\hat{\theta}_{BC}\}$.  This is for the case when $\hat{\theta}_{AB}$ and $\hat{\theta}_{BC}$ are estimated from independent samples.

Based on the figure linked to in the comments section I get 0.67 (0.44, 1.02) as the point estimate and 95% CI, which matches what the original poster calculated in the comments section.

NOTE: In my original solution I incorrectly provided inference on $\hat{\theta}_{AB}/\hat{\theta}_{BC}$ instead of $\hat{\theta}_{AB}\cdot\hat{\theta}_{BC}$.

Comment: Thanks very much. In fact, I have the Standard Error of the Estimate. Here is an example. Of course it isn't about pooling these effects but I make a forest plot to have the 3 results easy to see. https://www.zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=21/30/5wy1.jpg Supposing I have the 2 first lines, I want to compose them. Of course, I shouldn't get exactly the third line, because it was calculated directly. Using the 2 ORs should give a larger interval that the direct calculus. I tried and I get : exp(ln(1.43*0.47)+-1.96*sqrt(0.1533^2+0.1449^2)) ->[0.44,1.02] which seems consistent. Is it OK ?

Comment: That is what I get, too!  Since the figure you linked to pertains to meta-analysis, here is a paper I have drafted on the topic, [Transfer Learning via Meta-analysis](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/352192954_Transfer_Learning_via_Meta-analysis).

Answer (score 0):

It seems challenging with the information you have. You should be able to compute the OR of treatment A vs treatment C but you need for information for computing the CI. Here are some resources that you might find useful: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK431098/

Comment: Thanks. I wrote a mistake. I should obtain the CI99.875 of A vs C (not CI99.7) if I multiply the CI95 of A vs B with the CI95 of B vs C, since the probability of having both results at the same time being at the lower end of the CI is 0.025*0.025, same for the upper end, it means a probability of 0.00125 having get the current result if the effect is outside the multiplied CIs. Do you know about a method to obtain the CI95 once I have the CI 99.875 ?

Comment: No, unfortunately... but it should be possible actually.